# How to find month gaps in Oracle table?

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have a Oracle table which has EmpName (Char),Month_from and Month_to column (Numeric). Here I need to find missing months ( Month gaps). In the below sample data I have to find missing month 6 (Jun ).

Thanks in advance.

```
Sample Data:

|-------|-----------|--------|
|eName  |Month_From |Month_To|
|(Char) | ( Int)    | ( Int) |
|-------|------------|-------|
|John   |1          |2       | ( Jan to Feb)
|John   |3          |5       | ( Mar to May)
|John   |7          |8       | ( Jul to Aug)    
|-------|------------|-------|
```

Need to Find (Jun to Jun).

Comment: How do you (and we) know that 9 (Sept) is not missing also? If months may be missing, what guarantees that they cannot be missing at the beginning and/or the end of the sequence, and instead they can only be missing "within" the sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no overlaps, you can find the missing months using `lag()`:

```
select (prev_month_to + 1) as start_missing,
       (month_from - 1) as end_missing
from (select t.*, lag(month_to) over (partition by name order by month_from) as prev_month_to
      from t
     ) t
where prev_month_to <> month_from - 1;
```

This provides a range for each gap, because the gap could be more than one month.

Comment: Thanks for your help Linoff.

Answer (score 1):

Just conversion for the *sample data*, you may consider :

```
select to_char(to_date(lpad(t.month_from,2,'0'),'mm'),'Mon')||' to '||
       to_char(to_date(lpad(t.month_to,2,'0'),'mm'),'Mon')
  from my_table t
 where upper(t.eName) = upper('&i_eName');
```

For the question ( *Jun to Jun* ):

```
select to_char(to_date(lpad(a1.mon,2,'0'),'mm'),'Mon')
  from ( select level mon from dual connect by level <= 12 ) a1
 where not exists ( select null
                      from my_table a2
                     where a1.mon between a2.month_from and a2.month_to
                       and upper(a2.eName) = upper('&i_eName') )
 order by mon;
```

But, it returns also **Sep**, **Oct**, **Nov**, **Dec**, besides **Jun**. For this, i agree with @mathguy's comment.

Comment: I think you are missing the point that the OP wants to return "6", not the strings like "Jan to Feb".

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok, thank you i'm aware of the last sentence just now.

Comment: @GordonLinoff today, i could look at this for "Jun to Jun" part, thank you again.